# The Intellij IDEA does not launch after editing the VM options file, no config file available

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

In Intellij IDEA 2021.2.1 I mistakenly added incorrect lines to VM option file(Menu->Help->Edit Custom VM Option). After that, the IDEA does not launch. Reinstallation didn't help.
And I do not have any config file in intellij folder, all the solutions I found started in the config file (or configuration directory), that I dont have.

Comment: What O/S are you on?  You have a config file, we just need to find it.

Comment: Delete the file from the Configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869.

Comment: Windows 10.
When I enter Intellij Idea I have the following folders:  bin, help, jbr, lib, licence, plugin, redist, nothing more. I am trying to find it over2 hours.